# toggle on double click

Tags: jquery, toggle, double-click

looking a way to make a toggle on doubleclick, this is my code:

```
$('#mydiv').toggle(function() {
  $('#post').css({'height' : '188'});
}, function() {
  $('#post').css({'height' : '48'});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#mydiv').dblclick(function () {
  $('#post').height($('#post').height() > 100 ? 48 : 180);
});
```

Or may be you want this:

```
$(".generic-expand-button").each(function () {
    $(this).dblclick(function() {
        $(this).closest(".post").height($(this).closest(".post").height() > 100 ? 48 : 180);
    });
});
```

Comment: This works, but I'm looking a way to handle more selectors, any new idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: More selectors... as in `$('#mydiv .toggle-buttons') -> toggle("#post-" + somethingDynamicallyCalculated)`?

Comment: nope, on double click, I need want to modify more #, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `.each()` if you want to bind-to/modify more than one item. You may want to use classes instead of IDs. I'll edit my answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery double click event: http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/