# JQuery with .toggle .css

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that show 200 px. When I click on a image in the div I want to show 1000px.
Then close to 200px again when clicked once again.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // shows the slickbox DIV on clicking the link with an ID of "slick-show"

$('#slickbox').css("height", "200px");      
$('#slick-show').click(function() {
        $('#slickbox').toggle(function () {
    $("#slickbox").css("height", "1000px");
}, function () {
    $("#slickbox").css("height", "200px");
      });
});
return false;

});
</script>

<div id="slickbox" style="height: 1000px;">
<p style="text-align: center;">
<a id="slick-show" href="#"><img src="/ImageVaultFiles/id_468115/cf_69211/Happy_monday14-5.jpg" border="0" alt="Happy_monday14-5" /></a></p>
</div>
```

The code work but I have to doubleclick every time after the first opening.

Comment: check out this Question on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160150/toggle-on-double-click), may be this help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing `toggle`.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

> Description: Bind two or more handlers to the matched elements, to be executed on alternate clicks.

`toggle` should only be called once.  It will bind click handlers which will trigger on alternating clicks.  What you are doing is re-binding click handlers every time you click.  What you really want to do is something like this:

```
$('#slickbox').css("height", "200px");      
$('#slick-show').toggle(function () {
    $("#slickbox").css("height", "1000px");
}, function () {
    $("#slickbox").css("height", "200px");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

this becuase you attach toggle function after click on element, avoid .click:

```
   $(function() {
        // shows the slickbox DIV on clicking the link with an ID of "slick-show"

    $('#slickbox').css("height", "200px");      
    $('#slick-show').toggle(function () {
        $("#slickbox").css("height", "1000px");
    }, function () {
        $("#slickbox").css("height", "200px");
          });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The .click() and .toggle() are redundant -- .toggle() assumes someone's going to be clicking on an element. See description in docs: "Bind two or more handlers to the matched elements, to be executed on alternate clicks." Just leave out the .click() and you'll get the behavior you want..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slickbox').css("height", "200px");   
    $('#slick-show').toggle(function() {
        $("#slickbox").css("height", "1000px");
    }, function() {
            $("#slickbox").css("height", "200px");
      });   
})​
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS class for different styles or widths or heights or anything

and then use

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

for toggling any style

Comment: We are locked to a useless cms that makes is a pain in the a** to use classes in javascripting.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, your `toggle` function is incorrect. Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/LsdUQ/